# changeLogSync with maven

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, liquibase

I have a java ee project with a existing db-schema. Now I want to use liquibase for the db.

So I generated a changelog from my existing schema at the command line. Run that changelog against the existing database with `mvn liquibase:changeLogSync` and now I can work with liquibase without problems.

My question is: can I use the `changeLogSync` command within the project without executing it manuell? F.e. like I use new files with changesets:

```
<include file="changelogs/db.changelog1.xml"/>
```

Is there a similar way for `changeLogSync`, like this one in Ant:

```
<changeLogSync
        changeLogFile="${db.changelog.file}"
        driver="${database.driver}"
        url="${database.url}"
        username="${database.username}"
        password="${database.password}"
        classpathref="classpath"
        >
</changeLogSync>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Here's ours:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.5</version>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>${ojdbc.version}</version>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <configuration>
     <changeLogFile>${db.changelog.file}</changeLogFile>
     <driver>${database.driver}</driver>
     <url>${database.url}</url>
     <username>${database.username}</username>
     <password>${database.password}</password>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
     <execution>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
           <goal>changeLogSync</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Adjust of course for your own DB flavor and build phase preferences.

Comment: Where is the `changeLogSync`? I already have the automated `update` and the `configuration` for the db. I need the `changeLogSync` as it marks all `change sets` as ran against the database. F.e. when I include the `generatedChangeLog` file as well. The command marks the `changesets` in the file as run and liquibase doesnt try to run the commands and gets errors like "table already exists"

Comment: Just edited.  I might add this doesn't make a lot of sense for a build script; I don't think you'd want to changelogSync with every new change, you'd want to apply it.  But, hey, it's your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will check it out. No it doesnt make sense for every new change. I was thinking to use it only for the first time for a poject that has to be deployed on the production server with an already existing database. So the first version has this goal and you dont have to interfere manuell. Just deploying the project and it makes automatically the synch and then the updates. The following version would then just have the goal update.. Not sure though

Comment: We had the same challenge deploying Liquibase ourselves in production, and really had no alternative but to run the changelogSync command manually.  We used the Maven plugin, and the command you described in the original question.  For us, we found the greatest benefit from automating the update step, and leaving it as a one-off step to manually run changelogSync on our QA and production DBs.  Also, if you're happy with the answer, an accept would be greatly appreciated. I upvoted your question.

Comment: i havent forgot you. Just hadnt the time to test if `<goal>changeLogSync</goal>` works. Thanks for the sharing of your knowledge and experience :) Can you tell me what the benefits of `changelogSync` at all are? Maybe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603880/best-practice-to-expand-a-project-at-production-with-liquibase. I feel like I miss some point..

Comment: My experience is limited to a single project, so take this with a grain of salt.  We typically have three scenarios for Liquibase.  First, we must be able to build a working database from scratch.  Second, we must be able to apply new migrations seamlessly to all developers.  Finally, we must be able to migrate our QA and production DBs to liquibase for the initial changeover.  We used changelogSync for the case, but once the sync was applied, the production and QA dbs became special cases of #2, if that makes any sense.  So overwhelmingly, the best goal to automate was update.

Comment: (ran out of characters)... Liquibase handles the first two scenarios straight out of the box.  For our old db build scripts, we archived the SQL scripts we had used previously, integrated them as Liquibase migrations, and subsequently wrote all new DB changes as Liquibase migrations.

Comment: Thanks again for sharing this experience as examples :)