# best practice to expand a project at production with liquibase

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, liquibase

I have a java ee project with an existing database. Now I expand my project local by using the liquibase-maven-plugin. The project create automatically a `tag` and makes an `update`.

Are there any steps or preparations I have to take care of before deploying this project at the production?

Local f.e. I played with the `generateChangeLog` command, which creates a xml-schema file of the existing database. Do I need this file for any purpose?

Actually I just can set first of all a tag and then go on and work with liquibase and the database. Do I miss here something or is it really that easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be that easy. The goal should be to run liquibase update against your development and QA databases as you make your changes, then simply run liquibase update against your production database when you deploying your new code and it will just work.

Comment: So there is no need for the generateChangeLog? Not once before the first use of update?